# jugglingdb - Setting the primary key field

Tags: jugglingdb

Is it possible to set what field should be the "id" field? I'm defining my scheme with:

```
var Person = app.ormDb.define('person', {
    id          : { type: String, index: true, default: function () { return uuid.v4(); } },
    oAuthID     : { type: String, index: true },
    name        : { type: String },
    gender      : { type: String },
    birth       : { type: Date },
    email       : { type: String },
    imageID     : { type: String },
    favorites   : { type: JSON, default: function() { return {cars : [], animals : []}; } },
    date        : { type: Date, default: function() { return new Date(); } },
    updated     : { type: Date, default: function() { return new Date(); } }
});
```

and my defined `id` field shows up in MongoDB but when I use jugglingdb to lookup a person the returned value for Person.id is the MongoDB _id ObjectId value. so my `id` is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`_id` is reserved in MongoDB as the primary key. This would explain why it can't be changed. You can place any value into this as long as it's unique. Hope that helps.

There is also currently an [open issue](https://github.com/jugglingdb/mongodb-adapter/issues/28) in the jugglingdb-mongodb adapter. That addresses the reason why id is not returned. Basically if `object.id` exists when calling create it is removed before insert into the collection.